# How to make an Image Button continually clickable in android

Tags: android, imageview, imagebutton

I am developing an application that contains a favorite feature. When the user clicks an image button, it should change its background resource and does something depending on its current background resource. The problem is that I need the button to be continually clickable so that if the user accidentally added an item to favorites, he/she would be able to remove it from favorites.

Here's the **onClickListener** that does the changes, but it does it only one time inside my activity. Once the user changes the favorite status, he/she can't change it again unless he/she leaves the activity and resumes it again.

```
ImageButton fav = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fav);    
fav.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (item.getIsFav() == 1) {
                    fav.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav_dimed);
                    editFavorite("remove from favorites");
                } else if (item.getIsFav() == 0) {
                    fav.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav);
                    editFavorite("add to favorites");
                }
            }
        });
```

Any one to help please :)

Comment: Probably the variable `isFav` inside the `item` is not updated (always `1` or `0`), hence there is no effect to the subsequent click. Would you please also post the code for `editFavorite()`?

Comment: I am sure that when the user clicks the button, the value of isFav is changed according to its current value (if 1 it becomes 0, if 0 it becomes 1). The problem is not here, the problem is that the button itself becomes non clickable as soon as the user clicks it once.

Comment: Use Toggle and Check The Status Of The Toggle If It is On then add in Fav Else Remove

Comment: Since the cause is still not clear, I have some questions: How do you store `isFav`? I assume you are using SQLite? If yes, do you update the value directly to the DB, but not to the current `item`? If `editFavorite()` has something to do with updating `isFav`, could you post the relevant code here? And lastly, try adding `Log.i("OnClick", "Clicked");` inside `onClick()`, just above the `if-else` block. See whether the listener always responds to your click or not.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments.
@KaranMavadhiya: The problem is not the type of the used widget, they all do the same.

Comment: @antimo: I solved it. The problem was, exactly as you said, that I don't change the value of the current item. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

It may happen because you might be setting - fav button setClickable - false or setEnabled - false.

Are you sure you don't have something like this in your code ?

> fav.setEnabled(false); 
>     fav.setClickable(false);

Comment: No I don't. I've just added fav.setClickable(true); and fav.setEnabled(true); inside onClick() method body to make sure that it's clickable, but nothing changed!